# Other notions of vector independence besides linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering whether there are other notions of vector independence besides "linearly independent"?

This is a general question, but one example I had in mind is considering a pair like $[0,2,1,2,0,0,0]$ and $[0,0,0,0,2,1,2]$ to be dependent (even when considering cosine similarity -- these would yield $0$ but perhaps there's something else that captures this or other types of similarity).

I'm also not sure what tags to put here, so please edit if you have other ideas.

Comment: Well, there are group actions.  The symmetric group, $S_n$, acts on $\mathbb R^n$ by permuting the coordinates...your two vectors are equivalent under this action.

Comment: @lulu Nice one, thanks! I'm wondering now if there's something that would consider $[0, 1.999, 1, 1.999, 0, 0, 0]$ to be similar to $[0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2]$.

Comment: You can invent any relations you want.  Be wary of approximate ones though. If you say that, e.g., two vectors are equivalent if they are close in value, then you probably lose transitivity.  That is to say, if $A,B$ and $B,C$ are nearby pairs, maybe $A,C$ isn't.

Comment: The main reason that linear dependence is such a major focus is that linearity (in the sense of having operations relating to addition and scalar multiplication) is one of the key properties of vector spaces. If you invent a new kind of dependence it may not be generalisable to all vector spaces (e.g. if it depends on a finite dimension, or on a metric).